# Iterating through basic blocks without iterating through functions

Tags: llvm

if I want to examine all of the blocks in a given program irrespective of the function each belongs to is there a way to do so other than iterating over the functions and within each function iterating over the blocks? i.e block iterator rather than block iterator within a function iterator...

Comment: I'm afraid not, The Module keeps track of FunctionList and Function keeps track for BasicBlockList. see http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#module

Comment: You can write a basic block pass, which would let you just examine basic blocks, but that is also not iterating through them under your control.